# EJB-3.1 @Startup & @Schedule anotation in Apache Tomee for Timer Execution

Tags: java-ee-6, quartz-scheduler, ejb-3.1, schedule, apache-tomee

**I have following code to run on Apache-tomee, i am using eclipse for coding, and i want to run my simple schedule job using @Schedule annotation at application start-up.**

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class ScheduleEJB {
    private static int count = 0;
    @Schedule(second="*/10", minute="*", hour="*", info="MyTimer")
    public void execute() {
       System.out.println("its running count..."+count);
       count++;
    }
}
```

**When i deployed this code on Tomee, it get me following message and unable to run my schedule method execute() automatically at startup, where as this code works fine in glassfish, but i am not going to use it either glassfish of jboss.**


Dec 21, 2012 9:59:45 AM org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory instantiate

INFO: Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor

Dec 21, 2012 9:59:45 AM org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl 

INFO: Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl

Dec 21, 2012 9:59:45 AM org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler 

INFO: Quartz Scheduler v.2.1.6 created.

Dec 21, 2012 9:59:45 AM org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore initialize

INFO: RAMJobStore initialized.

Dec 21, 2012 9:59:45 AM org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler initialize

INFO: Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.1.6) 'OpenEJB-TimerService-Scheduler' with instanceId 'OpenEJB'

  ***Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.

  NOT STARTED.

  Currently in standby mode.

  Number of jobs executed: 0

  Using thread pool 'org.apache.openejb.core.timer.DefaultTimerThreadPoolAdapter' - with 0 threads.

  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.***



Dec 21, 2012 9:59:45 AM org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory instantiate

INFO: Quartz scheduler 'OpenEJB-TimerService-Scheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.

Dec 21, 2012 9:59:45 AM org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory instantiate

INFO: Quartz scheduler version: 2.1.6

Dec 21, 2012 9:59:45 AM org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler start

INFO: Scheduler OpenEJB-TimerService-Scheduler_$_OpenEJB started.

Dec 21, 2012 9:59:45 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication

INFO: Created Ejb(deployment-id=ScheduleEJB, ejb-name=ScheduleEJB, container=My Singleton Container)

Dec 21, 2012 9:59:45 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication

INFO: Started Ejb(deployment-id=ScheduleEJB, ejb-name=ScheduleEJB, container=My Singleton Container)

Answer (score 1):

Did you already have a look to TomEE examples page?
There is a similar example which actually running.

http://openejb.apache.org/examples-trunk/schedule-methods/README.html

Maybe you could give it a try and check what is actually different with yours.

Comment: yes, i have checked its the same thing, but my problem was not how to code it, was how i will be able to run that code in tomee, and interestingly what i found the solution, that if i run my project by deploying directly from eclipse on a running tomee server, it will not start the timer, but when i just deployed the app and restart the server it just start my timer, so i am unable to figure out the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs fine on last release of TomEE. What was your version?

Comment: it was apache-tomee-1.5.1-plus, yes it runs and working fine now, but for which i have to restart tomee after deploying my code... the reason i am unable to figure out